# Why does the live wire terminal say 450V?

Tags: electrical

I have three wall light fixtures that need to be wired in. There are two terminals - one is marked 450V, the other just has the manufacturer's name. I'm assuming the 450V terminal is for the live wire, but why does it say 450? The mains voltage here is 230. Is 450 the maximum potential difference the light can be safely exposed to?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the markings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the tires on your car.   See the codes? One of them is a speed rating (such as 220 kph).   Obviously you don't *need to* drive that fast.  The tires will still work if you go slower.  That's just how fast the tires are rated for.

Same thing here.  The wires are rated for up to 450V.